# Android - PHP - regex with letters of all languages

Tags: java, php, android, regex

Following my android code:

```
string.matches("[a-zA-Z ]+")
```

How to allow letters of all languages (and spaces)? How to do it with also with PHP function `preg_match()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Unicode property `\p{L}`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) which matches any kind of letter from any language.

```
[\\p{L} ]+
```

You can use it like so with PHP's [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) function:

```
preg_match('/^[\p{L} ]+$/u', $str, $match);
```

Comment: PHP code works, but Android code doesn't work. Error is: 
Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )